# <text> в svg смещается по горизонтали в Firefox/Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, текст

Если смотреть относительно `<path>`, то можно заметить, что текст смещается вправо в браузерах Firefox и Safari.
Эмпирическим путем понял, что без пробела между словами всё отображается без смещения. Если добавить свойство `word-spacing:-4px;` в Firefox/Safari все отлично, но смещается Chrome.
Как это поправить?

```html
<svg version="1.1" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 395 338" style="enable-background:new 0 0 395 338;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,500;1,500");
        .st0{fill:#0F2341;}
        .st1{font-family:"Playfair Display";font-weight:500;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}
        .st2{font-size:74.8867px;}
        .st3{fill:#4EAE33;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M241,119h-36l-11-33l-11,32h-36l28,21l-10,32l29-19l29,19l-11-32L241,119z M202,145l-8-6l-9,6l3-10l-8-6h10l4-9
        l3,9h10l-8,6L202,145z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 40 108)" class="st0 st1 st2">HT WITH</text>
    <path class="st0" d="M241,258.4h-36l-11-33l-11,32h-36l28,21l-10,32l29-19l29,19l-11-32L241,258.4z M202,284.4l-8-6l-9,6l3-10l-8-6
        h10l4-9l3,9h10l-8,6L202,284.4z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 54 248)" class="st0 st1 st2">HTWITH</text>
    <line class="st3" x1="194" y1="23" x2="194" y2="308.9"/>
</svg>
```

Код: https://codepen.io/jamesscreen/pen/KKyPZeE

Comment: Замените обычный пробел на неразрывный - `&nbsp;`

Comment: На Codepen `&nbsp;` сработает, но на сайте это вызовет ошибку. Лучший вариант: `&#160;`. Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Используя `&#160;` вместо пробелов, проблема решилась.